# How to calculate current row base on previous row in sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a table name "van":

[image]

I want to add a column f follow this formula using an SQL select query:

f[i] = (f[i - 1] * 13 + a[i])/14

f[0] = 0

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the results you want, you need to use a recursive CTE because the computed value of `f` depends on the value computed in the previous step.

Here is how it can be achieved in SQL Server

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CAST(0 AS float) f -- set 0 to f[0] and cast it to float to get decimal results
    FROM van
    WHERE id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        van.*,
        ROUND((cte.f * 13 + van.a) / 14, 6) -- f[i] = (f[i - 1] * 13 + a[i])/14, round value to 6 decimal places
    FROM van
    JOIN cte ON van.id = cte.id + 1
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Query output

| id | a | f |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 0.357143 |
| 2 | 6 | 0.760204 |
| 3 | 9 | 1.348761 |
| 4 | 11 | 2.038135 |
| 5 | 4 | 2.178268 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28d0afba615e204235267f72b632a271)*

Comment: Wao!!. That is amazing. Let me test and apply to my actual problem and tell you soon. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you write this solution in athena SQL?

Comment: When I run your solution in athena, it says "Table awsdatacatalog.cte does not exist"

Comment: According to the Athena docs - * Using the WITH clause to create recursive queries is not supported. * see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/select.html There is no solution in Athena I'm afraid. You can try creating a new question with the `athena` tag to get the attention of users who are familiar with it.